# How to run stand-alone Javascript in Blazor

Tags: javascript, blazor

How can I run some Javascript functions in a Blazor app, **without using the JS interop** or jQuery? Just plain old Javascript functions that interact with the DOM, independently of Blazor.

I added my script right before the closing `</body>` tag:

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

And in app.js I have the following:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".some-element");

elements.forEach(function (element) {
    element.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        alert("Hello");
    });
});
```

Of course the selector finds no element. I'm guessing they aren't yet present in the DOM at that point? *How can I run that script **without using the JS interop** or jQuery?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your okay with using jquery you can use an on handler, which will apply to dynamically added elements

```
$("body").on("click", ".some-element", function(){
  alert("Hello");
});
```

You can do natively too, but seems sketchy IMHO:

```
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.className.toLowerCase() === 'some-element') {
      alert("Hello");
  }
});
```

Note you have weird javascripty things to worry about now like z-index if the click event actually gets up to the body, but it should work for simple stuff.

Main question is **WHY** would you want to do this in Blazor - whole point is you can use C# events instead you crazy person!!

Comment: I was trying to get away from big fat jQuery after over a decade of use. Now that browsers are a little less crappy, that seems possible. I would LOVE to get rid of this junk that JS is, but unfortunately Webassembly has no access to the DOM, so I can't get/set DOM elements such as width, height, etc. within Blazor. I guess I can call JS functions from C# thanks to the interop, but, would prefer to keep JS separate and in its own little bubble away from the Blazor goodness (might help with performance as well). It's just for design stuff only, so I don't need the retrieved values in the C#

Comment: @BlazingNoob - you dont NEED to get DOM elements like width and height - You bind them to C# Properties, then you use the C# properties instead!!!! I think you are missing the point of Blazor completely...

Comment: I scratched my head trying to understand your message (open mind), but I'm afraid you haven't got a firm grasp on Blazor yourself. Like I said, wasm has no access to the DOM, therefore you CAN'T retrieve a DOM element in Blazor. Once the browser renders the HTML generated by Blazor into a DOM tree, it's out of Blazor's hands. Binding in Blazor has nothing to do with the DOM, it's internal binding within Blazor. You can't retrieve the final properties of the rendered DOM elements in Blazor such as width/height. That is when JS comes in, hence my question. TY for answering the initial question.

Comment: @BlazingNoob - Not really sure what you mean.... look at my new answer below for an example of what I was talking about. I have never needed to directly interact with the DOM in any of my Blazor apps and have created some complicated web applications that completely replaced existing traditional ones. You sometimes just need to change your way of thinking so you are using C# instead of javascript...

Comment: sometimes its way easier to let javasript handle things you dont want to care about like 300 items menu with toggling, animation and lots of css classes switching etc

Answer (score 0):

Create a page like this:

```
<div height="@($"{Height}px")" width="@($"{Width}px")">
    Test
</div>

<button @onclick="DoubleSize">Double Size</button>

@code
{
    public int Width { get; set; } = 50;

    public int Height { get; set; } = 50;

    private void DoubleSize()
    {
        Width = Width * 2;
        Height = Height * 2;
    }
}
```

On render the height and width are 50px:

[image]

Then you click the Button, and they change to 100px:

[image]

Similarly with CSS if that's what you were talking about:

```
<div style="width: @($"{Width}px"); height: @($"{Height}px")">
    Test
</div>
```

[image]

This is interacting with the properties of the DOM elements without using Javascript... you can do this with any property. You don't need to use Javascript - you just bind them to your properties in C#...

You shouldn't need to 'retrieve the final properties of the rendered DOM elements' as you should be controlling them from C# and not worrying about the DOM

Comment: the problem is when you want to get the dimensions of an html element (not when you want change), or focus an input, or create a document listener (mouse down, keyup...). For me the ElementRef should has this properties/events -like e.g. Angular- but nowadays it's not possible only with Blazor

Comment: @Eliseo - Yes but if you set them in the first place - you don't need to get them... You just need to change your way of thinking. If you bind the height property to a C# property called height, then you can just look at your C# property - you don't need to get it from the DOM element, cause you know the DOM element has the value you set. Again with events - if you set them on the element using a C# method, then you can handle the event in C#. If you can post a concrete example scenario where you think this isn't possible then I'd be interested to see it, or show you how to do it with C#

Comment: @Minney, Easy, I'll try to make a datepicker - yes it's only an exercise- I write an `<input>` and a `<div>here my calendar</div>` that has visibility hidden or visible. I don't know the dimensions of the div because this dimensions are relationated with .css (you can, e.g. make the font-size bigger) and you can show two or more months). I need know the dimensions of the `input` and the dimension of the `div` to show the "calendar" at bottom of the input or up the input, to the left or to the rigth. For me is imposible if I don't use a call to javascript

Comment: @Eliseo - You absolutely do not need to know the dimensions of the div to do that. Your component can simply render the required elements before or after the actual <input>, and use CSS to position it relatively - have a look at https://github.com/jdtcn/BlazorDateRangePicker for an example. Now that example does actually use some Interop for advanced scenarios - but if you run it without it can still totally position correctly in the vast majority of cases. You could change the bit using interop, if you controlled the rest of the page, its just doing that cause its a library

Comment: i.e. if you control the height and width of the container element too - you can simply reference them and don't need to use javascript to find them

Comment: @Milney, I think you've misunderstood my reasons. As I've been trying to explain, I need to know the size of divs AFTER the browser renders them. I CAN'T set their size in Blazor because they are dynamically sized by the browser to fit their content. Only AFTER the browser sizes the divs to their content, do I need to A: retrieve the size of the largest of 3 divs, B: set that size to the remaining 2 divs, so that all 3 divs are the same size. No way to do that in pure Blazor, hence the need for JS. I didn't want to use JS Interop and wanted to do this in pure JS, which you did answer before.

Comment: idk if I miss sth here, but the disccusion seems very tunnel-sighted. I've come here bc I was wondering the same thing. AND NO... BLAZOR can absolutely NOT fullfill many things related directly to the DOM. ESPECIALLY GETTING (dynamic) info FROM elements. ElementRef basically can only be used for setting target and nothing else. Assume you want to display counter+button for how many items in a wrapped flexbox are in line 1 of a responsive layout (dependent on other elements and viewport and user input) - tell be a pure C#/Blazor way please, that would be great. I don't think thats possible.

Comment: one more: deciding if the intrinsic w/h of an img src is w<h or w>h and in response to that set different css width/height. there's no C# nor a pure CSS way for that.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty new in Blazor, so sorry if it's not the correct way to do it in Balzor. But I think that you need always use JS interop to use JavaScript function. You want to execute some script, but the question is: when do you want to execute the script?  I imagine you want to execute an action after navigate to a page, after make a click in a button... and all this events happens in Blazor

If you ask about relationate an blazor element with the doom you need use `@ref`

A little example. You create a .js like

```
var auxiliarJs = auxiliarJs || {};
auxiliarJs.getBoundingClientRect = function (elementRef) {
    let result = elementRef? elementRef.getBoundingClientRect():
                {left: 0,top: 0,right: 0,bottom: 0,x: 0,y: 0,width: 0,height: 0 };
    return result;
}
auxiliarJs.executeFunction = function (elementRef, funciones) {
    let res = null;
    try {
        if (Array.isArray(funciones)) {
            functiones.forEach(funcion => {
                elementRef[funcion]()
            });
        }
        else
            res = elementRef[funciones]();
    }
    catch (e) { }

    if (res)
        return res;
}
auxiliarJs.setDocumentTitle = function (title) {
        document.title = title;
    };
```

And a service.cs with his interface

```
public interface IDocumentService
{
    Task<ClientRect> getBoundingClientRect(ElementReference id);
    Task setDocumentTitle(string title);
    Task<JsonElement> executeFunction(ElementReference id, string funcion);
    Task executeFunction(ElementReference id, string[] funciones);
}

public class DocumentService:IDocumentService
{
    private IJSRuntime jsRuntime;

    public DocumentService(IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
    {
        this.jsRuntime = jsRuntime;
    }
    public Dictionary<string, object> JSonElementToDictionary(JsonElement result)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> obj = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        JsonProperty[] enumerador = result.EnumerateObject().GetEnumerator().ToArray();

        foreach (JsonProperty prop in enumerador)
        {
            obj.Add(prop.Name, prop.Value);
        }
        return obj;
    }

    public async Task<ClientRect> getBoundingClientRect(ElementReference id)
    {
        return await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<ClientRect>("auxiliarJs.getBoundingClientRect", id);
    }
    
    public async Task setDocumentTitle(string title)
    {
        await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("auxiliarJs.setDocumentTitle", title);

    }
    public async Task<JsonElement> executeFunction(ElementReference id,string funcion)
    {
        var result= await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<JsonElement>
                         ("auxiliarJs.executeFunction", id, funcion);
        return result;

    }
    public async Task executeFunction(ElementReference id, string[] funciones)
    {
        await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("auxiliarJs.executeFunction", id, funciones);
    }
}

public class ClientRect
{
    public float left{ get; set; }
    public float top { get; set; }
    public float right { get; set; }
    public float bottom { get; set; }
    public float x { get; set; }
    public float y { get; set; }
    public float width { get; set; }
    public float height { get; set; }
}
```

Well, you inject the service as usual in program.cs

```
    public static async Task Main(string[] args){
       ....
       builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDocumentService, DocumentService>();
    }
```

And in your component razor

```
@inject IDocumentService document

<div @ref="mydiv"></div>
<input @ref="myinput">
<button @onclick="click">click</button>

@code{  
    private ElementReference mydiv;
    private ElementReference myinput;

    click(){
      ClientRect rect = await document.getBoundingClientRect(mydiv);
      document.setDocumentTitle("New Title");
      document.executeFunction(myinput 'focus')
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, JS Interop is definitely the way to tie blazor events to Javascript functions. But the interop comes with a performance cost, which I was hoping to avoid if I can run these JS functions on their own. Today my use case is retrieving DOM width/height for one element and applying it to the DOM width/height of other elements (for design purpose). I don't need Blazor to trigger it or be aware of this activity at all.

Comment: Repeat my comment, you need execute your javascript after one event happens in blazor (possible candidate `OnAfterRender()` of your component) I can't imagine another option

Answer (score -1):

Blazor "overwrites" all attached JS Events during render process

```
window.attachHandlers = () => {
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".some-element");
elements.forEach(function (element) {
element.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    alert("Hello");
});
```

});

and in razor page

```
 protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
{
    if(firstRender)
    {

    JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("attachHandlers");
    }
}
```